# How to compress your django project ( along w/ the dependent Python modules ) into one file that can be run on a server

Tags: python, django

The basic core of the problem I've expressed being - portability of the Django Project.

I want to give my testing team the project as a single file. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[disutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) will allow you to package your project into a single archive that can be extracted and installed.

Comment: This is so awesome! So the testers can just do a - python setup.py install on my project and then get the manage.py runserver working? And this does take care of PIL dependencies and all the likewise right?

Comment: You'll need to use something more sophisticated than distutils if you want to handle dependencies; either of setuptools or distribute should do.

Comment: I was looking for more of a .jar file kind of solution that's available with Java

Comment: So then an egg. But you still need the distutils basics down for that.